# Multiline String information ordered?

Tags: geojson

I am relatively new to this whole geotopic. I have to deal with the following scenario:

From a userperspective, I do three steps

- I draw a straight line across a riverbed
- I get a resultset from the server back
- A diagram is drawn where the x-axis has relative distanceinformation from where the points are along the line and the y-axis gives me altitude information of the riverbed

As a programmer, I get GeoJSON which contains `Multiline String` information (because the data is segmented?).

The overall structure is simply an array of two dimensional arrays

```
[
 [[long, lat, alt], ...$segment1],
 [$segment2],
 ...
]
```

To retrieve the distance information (where in relation to a starting point is a given point?) I pick the first segment's first point triple as a referenec point.

From there I calculate successive the distances for the following points.

As a result, I would expect something like this:

```
segment1: [0, y1], [1, y2] ... [n, yn]
segment2: [n+1, yn+1] ...
```

What I really get is something like:

```
segment1: [0, y1], [1, y2] ... [n, yn]
segment10: [2, y10] ...
```

Which I find quite confusing.

I assumed the segments to be ordered somehow, so that I get a rising monotonously result.

Comment: this is probably something you need to discuss with the server's programmer to find out what they think they are sending you. To answer this we would need to see the actual output (at least).

Comment: More confusing is, that this question is put on hold "unclear what you are asking". The question seems obvious: »Multiline String information ordered?« Possible answer: No, as it is not specified. Anyways: After digging deeper, I came to the conclusion, that the data, the server sent was _crap_. I got a straight line, which I could verify at geojson.io. But the segments are ordered randomly, which makes proper calculation difficult. @Ian Turton: yes, they thought they serve proper data, but the data in postgres seems to be corrupted and in consequence, I get rubbish.